# How can I use my own template with Django auth_views?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am creating the option for users to change their passwords, and for this I am using Django `auth_views`, specifically PasswordChangeView (CBV). Django `auth_views` by default use the Django admin design template. How can I use my own template with only the form of `auth_views`?

#### What I tried:

I'm trying to set a `template_name`. But the `auth_views` form won't appear...
Only the template I provide will load.

#### urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns = [
    path('change-password/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='settings/alterar_passwor 
d.html'), name="change-password"),

]
```

#### Template

**alterar_password.html**

```
{% extends 'settings/settings.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block settings %}


 <a href="{% url 'change-password' %}">Mudar a minha password</a>

{% endblock %}
```

**What I expect:**
I'm looking forward to use the form provided from `auth_views`, with the my own template, so I can avoid Django admin design for users.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is that the full template? If so of course the form doesn't appear,.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm passing my template through template name in the url. the form doesn't show, how can I fix it?

Comment: Obviously you have to render it somewhere like this {{ form.as_p }} in template you are passing.

Comment: @NafeesAnwar I though there would be a simple way to do this. I understand using {{ form.as_p }} but in this case I don't have access to the form. I'm using a view from the auth_views module. I thought that by passing the template in the URL, it would automatically adjust the form to my template.

Comment: @NafeesAnwar from the Django Docs:
template_name: The full name of a template to use for displaying the password change form. Defaults to registration/password_change_form.html if not supplied.

Comment: @Jaime38130 Please add full contents of `settings/alterar_passwor 
d.html` file in your question.

Comment: What do you mean, you don't have access to the form? If course you do. You have access to all the elements from that view.

Comment: @NafeesAnwar I edited

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I was not aware about that. how can I find out the name of the form and its fields?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I got it, I can access through {{ form }}, as lately I've been using multiple forms with different names, I didn't realize auth_views would use "form" as a default for the form itself. Thank you for looking into my problem

Comment: @NafeesAnwar I understand now! I got it working. I was not aware of the auth_views functioning. I can access through {{ form }}. Thank you for looking into my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this or similiar code in your template. Your view will pass standard "form" in your custom template and you have to render it there.

an example:

```
    <form method="post" >
<fieldset>
    <legend>Password change</legend>
                        {%  csrf_token %}
                        {{form.as_p}}

<button type="submit" class="form-button ">Submit</button>

<button type="reset" class="form-button btn ">Reset</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: This worked! Exactly the result I expected. I initially thought that this step would have been automatic. Thank you Aleksei Khatkevich

Comment: You welcome. Please confirm my answer by clicking "V' button at the left side of the answer.